# Boot Camp 6 update won't install on Windows 10

Tags: bootcamp, windows

Using *Apple Software Update* gets an installer error when trying to update Boot Camp from 5.1 to 6.0 on a MacBook Pro retina laptop running Windows 10. Also tried downloading the Boot Camp drivers directly from Boot Camp Assistant and get the same errors (see screenshot).

The first error is an installer error; if I click *Close the program*, then I see and empty error message.

Any idea how to resolve this?

[image: Boot Camp install starting up]

[image: Boot Camp installer stopped working]

[image: Boot Camp empty error message]

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while sine I tried this so my apologies if it is a little vague... But the actual Windows drivers are inside the BootCamp package. In a zip file if memory serves.

Right-click on the bootcamp app and look for the drivers zip file (should be obvious which one it is.) and copy it out.

Put it in a place that your Win 10 installation can see it, boot into windows, copy the file over, open it up and install the drivers. One at a time if necessary in Windows.

Comment: Yes, the Apple Drivers are in the BootCamp\Drivers\Apple folder. I should have mentioned this in the question, but I did install all of them manually --  no errors, but Boot Camp still says 5.1 so something still isn't updated.

Comment: Most likely some Mac-side drivers. However if everything works as planned and both the Mac and Windows side is happy and you are having no problems. I would not sweat the version numbers and just use it.